# Erro ao fazer relacionamento Hibernate com Java

Tags: java, hibernate, session, relacionamento

Boa tarde galera! Estou com uma dúvida no Hibernate.
Tenho o seguinte caso
Pessoa
- Cliente
- Fornecedor

Mas não estou conseguindo fazer o relacionamento.
segue meus códigos

**Novo Erro**

```
18:50:34,405 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] - 
    select
        SEQ_CLIENTE.nextval 
    from
        dual
Hibernate: 
    select
        SEQ_CLIENTE.nextval 
    from
        dual
18:50:34,534 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] - 
    select
        SEQ_PESSOA.nextval 
    from
        dual
Hibernate: 
    select
        SEQ_PESSOA.nextval 
    from
        dual
18:50:34,630 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] - 
    /* insert model.PessoaModel
        */ insert 
        into
            PESSOA
            (PES_ATIVO, PES_BAIRRO, PES_CADASTRO, PES_CELULAR, PES_CEP, PES_CIDADE, PES_COMPLEMENTO, PES_CPFCNPJ, PES_EMAIL, PES_ENDERECO, PES_FANTASIA, PES_FISICA, PES_FONE1, PES_FONE2, PES_NOME, PES_NUMERO, PES_RGIE, PES_SITE, PES_UF, PES_CODIGO) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert model.PessoaModel
        */ insert 
        into
            PESSOA
            (PES_ATIVO, PES_BAIRRO, PES_CADASTRO, PES_CELULAR, PES_CEP, PES_CIDADE, PES_COMPLEMENTO, PES_CPFCNPJ, PES_EMAIL, PES_ENDERECO, PES_FANTASIA, PES_FISICA, PES_FONE1, PES_FONE2, PES_NOME, PES_NUMERO, PES_RGIE, PES_SITE, PES_UF, PES_CODIGO) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
18:50:34,631 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [1] as [CHAR] - [S]
18:50:34,631 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
18:50:34,634 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [3] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Thu Nov 01 18:50:31 BRT 2018]
18:50:34,634 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
18:50:34,634 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
18:50:34,635 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
18:50:34,635 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [7] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
18:50:34,635 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [8] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
18:50:34,635 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [9] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
18:50:34,635 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [10] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
18:50:34,635 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [11] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
18:50:34,635 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [12] as [CHAR] - [S]
18:50:34,635 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [13] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
18:50:34,635 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [14] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
18:50:34,635 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [15] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
18:50:34,636 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [16] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
18:50:34,636 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [17] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
18:50:34,636 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [18] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
18:50:34,636 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [19] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
18:50:34,636 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [20] as [INTEGER] - [35]
18:50:34,921 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] - 
    /* insert model.ClienteModel
        */ insert 
        into
            CLIENTE
            (CLI_LIMITECRED, PES_CODIGO, CLI_CODIGO) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert model.ClienteModel
        */ insert 
        into
            CLIENTE
            (CLI_LIMITECRED, PES_CODIGO, CLI_CODIGO) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?)
18:50:34,922 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [1] as [DOUBLE] - [1.0]
18:50:34,923 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [35]
18:50:34,923 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] - binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [34]
18:50:35,141 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - SQL Error: 2291, SQLState: 23000
18:50:35,141 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - ORA-02291: restrição de integridade (UNIP.FK_CLIENTE) violada - chave mãe não localizada
```

**erro**

```
nov 01, 2018 2:24:51 PM org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions logCannotResolveNonNullableTransientDependencies
WARN: HHH000437: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. The unsaved transient entity must be saved in an operation prior to saving these dependent entities.
    Unsaved transient entity: ([model.PessoaModel#0])
    Dependent entities: ([[model.ClienteModel#6]])
    Non-nullable association(s): ([model.ClienteModel.pessoamodel])
```

**Erro após uma modificação no relacionamento do hibernate**
**Modificação de EAGER Para LAZY**

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

**Erro após modificação**

```
    Hibernate: select SEQ_CLIENTE.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select SEQ_PESSOA.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into PESSOA (PES_ATIVO, PES_BAIRRO, PES_CADASTRO, PES_CELULAR, PES_CEP, PES_CIDADE, PES_COMPLEMENTO, PES_CPFCNPJ, PES_EMAIL, PES_ENDERECO, PES_FANTASIA, PES_FISICA, PES_FONE1, PES_FONE2, PES_NOME, PES_NUMERO, PES_RGIE, PES_SITE, PES_UF, PES_CODIGO) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into CLIENTE (CLI_LIMITECRED, PES_CODIGO, CLI_CODIGO) values (?, ?, ?)
nov 01, 2018 2:58:30 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 2291, SQLState: 23000
nov 01, 2018 2:58:30 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-02291: restrição de integridade (UNIP.FK_CLIENTE_PESSOA) violada - chave mãe não localizada

nov 01, 2018 2:58:30 PM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
```

**Model Cliente**

```
package model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENTE")
public class ClienteModel implements java.io.Serializable {


    private int CLI_CODIGO;
    private Double CLI_LIMITECRED;
    private PessoaModel pessoamodel;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CLI_CODIGO", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 38, scale = 0)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_CLIENTE", sequenceName = "SEQ_CLIENTE", allocationSize = 0)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQ_CLIENTE", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    public int getCLI_CODIGO() {
        return CLI_CODIGO;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PES_CODIGO", nullable = false)
    public PessoaModel getPessoamodel() {
        return pessoamodel;
    }

    public void setPessoamodel(PessoaModel pessoamodel) {
        this.pessoamodel = pessoamodel;
    }

    public void setCLI_CODIGO(int CLI_CODIGO) {
        this.CLI_CODIGO = CLI_CODIGO;
    }



    @Column(name = "CLI_LIMITECRED", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 38, scale = 0)
    public Double getCLI_LIMITECRED() {
        return CLI_LIMITECRED;
    }

    public void setCLI_LIMITECRED(Double CLI_LIMITECRED) {
        this.CLI_LIMITECRED = CLI_LIMITECRED;
    }




}
```

**Model Pessoa**

```
    package model;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PESSOA")
public class PessoaModel implements java.io.Serializable {
    private int PES_CODIGO;
    private String PES_NOME;
    private String PES_FANTASIA;
    private char PES_FISICA;
    private String PES_CPFCNPJ;
    private String PES_RGIE;

    private Date PES_CADASTRO = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    private String PES_ENDERECO;
    private String PES_NUMERO;
    private String PES_COMPLEMENTO;
    private String PES_BAIRRO;
    private String PES_CIDADE;
    private String PES_UF;
    private String PES_CEP;
    private String PES_FONE1;
    private String PES_FONE2;
    private String PES_CELULAR;
    private String PES_SITE;
    private String PES_EMAIL;
    private char PES_ATIVO;

    public PessoaModel() {
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PES_CODIGO", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 38, scale = 0)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_PESSOA", sequenceName = "SEQ_PESSOA", allocationSize = 0)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQ_PESSOA", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)

    public int getPES_CODIGO() {
        return PES_CODIGO;
    }

    public void setPES_CODIGO(int PES_CODIGO) {
        this.PES_CODIGO = PES_CODIGO;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_NOME", length = 80)
    public String getPES_NOME() {
        return PES_NOME;
    }

    public void setPES_NOME(String PES_NOME) {
        this.PES_NOME = PES_NOME;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_FANTASIA", length = 80)
    public String getPES_FANTASIA() {
        return PES_FANTASIA;
    }

    public void setPES_FANTASIA(String PES_FANTASIA) {
        this.PES_FANTASIA = PES_FANTASIA;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_FISICA", length = 1)
    public char getPES_FISICA() {
        return PES_FISICA;
    }

    public void setPES_FISICA(char PES_FISICA) {
        this.PES_FISICA = PES_FISICA;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_CPFCNPJ", length = 20)
    public String getPES_CPFCNPJ() {
        return PES_CPFCNPJ;
    }

    public void setPES_CPFCNPJ(String PES_CPFCNPJ) {
        this.PES_CPFCNPJ = PES_CPFCNPJ;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_RGIE", length = 20)
    public String getPES_RGIE() {
        return PES_RGIE;
    }

    public void setPES_RGIE(String PES_RGIE) {
        this.PES_RGIE = PES_RGIE;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "PES_CADASTRO", nullable = false, length = 7)
    public Date getPES_CADASTRO() {
        return PES_CADASTRO;
    }

    public void setPES_CADASTRO(Date PES_CADASTRO) {
        this.PES_CADASTRO = PES_CADASTRO;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_ENDERECO", length = 120)
    public String getPES_ENDERECO() {
        return PES_ENDERECO;
    }

    public void setPES_ENDERECO(String PES_ENDERECO) {
        this.PES_ENDERECO = PES_ENDERECO;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_NUMERO", length = 10)
    public String getPES_NUMERO() {
        return PES_NUMERO;
    }

    public void setPES_NUMERO(String PES_NUMERO) {
        this.PES_NUMERO = PES_NUMERO;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_COMPLEMENTO", length = 30)
    public String getPES_COMPLEMENTO() {
        return PES_COMPLEMENTO;
    }

    public void setPES_COMPLEMENTO(String PES_COMPLEMENTO) {
        this.PES_COMPLEMENTO = PES_COMPLEMENTO;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_BAIRRO", length = 50)
    public String getPES_BAIRRO() {
        return PES_BAIRRO;
    }

    public void setPES_BAIRRO(String PES_BAIRRO) {
        this.PES_BAIRRO = PES_BAIRRO;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_CIDADE", length = 80)
    public String getPES_CIDADE() {
        return PES_CIDADE;
    }

    public void setPES_CIDADE(String PES_CIDADE) {
        this.PES_CIDADE = PES_CIDADE;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_UF", length = 2)
    public String getPES_UF() {
        return PES_UF;
    }

    public void setPES_UF(String PES_UF) {
        this.PES_UF = PES_UF;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_CEP", length = 9)
    public String getPES_CEP() {
        return PES_CEP;
    }

    public void setPES_CEP(String PES_CEP) {
        this.PES_CEP = PES_CEP;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_FONE1", length = 15)
    public String getPES_FONE1() {
        return PES_FONE1;
    }

    public void setPES_FONE1(String PES_FONE1) {
        this.PES_FONE1 = PES_FONE1;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_FONE2", length = 15)
    public String getPES_FONE2() {
        return PES_FONE2;
    }

    public void setPES_FONE2(String PES_FONE2) {
        this.PES_FONE2 = PES_FONE2;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_CELULAR", length = 15)
    public String getPES_CELULAR() {
        return PES_CELULAR;
    }

    public void setPES_CELULAR(String PES_CELULAR) {
        this.PES_CELULAR = PES_CELULAR;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_SITE", length = 200)
    public String getPES_SITE() {
        return PES_SITE;
    }

    public void setPES_SITE(String PES_SITE) {
        this.PES_SITE = PES_SITE;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_EMAIL", length = 200)
    public String getPES_EMAIL() {
        return PES_EMAIL;
    }

    public void setPES_EMAIL(String PES_EMAIL) {
        this.PES_EMAIL = PES_EMAIL;
    }

    @Column(name = "PES_ATIVO", length = 1)
    public char getPES_ATIVO() {
        return PES_ATIVO;
    }

    public void setPES_ATIVO(char PES_ATIVO) {
        this.PES_ATIVO = PES_ATIVO;
    }


}
```

**Cliente Controller**

```
package controller;

import dao.ClienteDao;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import model.ClienteModel;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import util.ReportUtils;

public class ClienteController implements GenericController<ClienteModel> {

    ClienteDao clientedao;

    public ClienteController() {
        clientedao = new ClienteDao();
    }

    @Override
    public void incluir(ClienteModel obj) throws Exception{
        clientedao.incluir(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void alterar(ClienteModel obj) throws Exception{
        clientedao.alterar(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void excluir(ClienteModel obj) throws Exception{
        clientedao.excluir(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<ClienteModel> consultar(String filtro) {
        return clientedao.consultar(filtro);
    }

    @Override
    public void gravar(ClienteModel obj, String operacao) throws Exception{
        if (operacao.equals("incluir")) {
            incluir(obj);
        } else {
            alterar(obj);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Exception imprimir() {
        Exception retorno = null;
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/relatorios/RelatorioCompra.jasper");
//        btnPRIMEIRO.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/primeiro.png"))); // NOI18N

        Map parametros = new HashMap();

        List dados = consultar("");

        // criando o datasource com os dados criados
        JRDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dados);

        try {
            // passando o datasource para o método de criação e exibição do relatório
            ReportUtils.openReport("Compras - Bean Collection Data Source", inputStream, parametros, ds);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            retorno =  ex;
        }
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

**Pessoa Controller**

```
package controller;

import dao.PessoaDao;
import dao.ClienteDao;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import model.PessoaModel;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import util.ReportUtils;


public class PessoaController implements GenericController<PessoaModel> {

    PessoaDao pessoadao;
    ClienteDao clientedao;

    public PessoaController() {
        pessoadao = new PessoaDao();
        clientedao = new ClienteDao();
    }



    @Override
    public void incluir(PessoaModel obj) throws Exception{

        pessoadao.incluir(obj); 
    }


    @Override
    public void alterar(PessoaModel obj) throws Exception{
        pessoadao.alterar(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void excluir(PessoaModel obj) throws Exception{
        pessoadao.excluir(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<PessoaModel> consultar(String filtro) {
        return pessoadao.consultar(filtro);
    }

    @Override
    public void gravar(PessoaModel obj, String operacao) throws Exception{
        if (operacao.equals("incluir")) {
            incluir(obj);
        } else {
            alterar(obj);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Exception imprimir() {
        Exception retorno = null;
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/relatorios/RelatorioCompra.jasper");
//        btnPRIMEIRO.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/primeiro.png"))); // NOI18N

        Map parametros = new HashMap();

        List dados = consultar("");

        // criando o datasource com os dados criados
        JRDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dados);

        try {
            // passando o datasource para o método de criação e exibição do relatório
            ReportUtils.openReport("Compras - Bean Collection Data Source", inputStream, parametros, ds);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            retorno =  ex;
        }
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

**Cliente DAO**

```
package dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import model.ClienteModel;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import util.HibernateUtil;

public class ClienteDao {

    public Exception incluir(ClienteModel obj) {
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(obj);
            t.commit();
            session.close();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex;
        }
    }

    public Exception alterar(ClienteModel obj) {
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(obj);
            t.commit();
            session.close();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<ClienteModel> consultar(String filtro) {
        String sql = "from " + ClienteModel.class.getName() + filtro;

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        ArrayList lista = (ArrayList<ClienteModel>) session.createQuery(sql).list();
        t.commit();
        session.close();
        return lista;
    }

    public Exception excluir(ClienteModel pessoa) {
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(pessoa);
            t.commit();
            session.close();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex;
        }
    }

    public ClienteModel get(long id) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        return (ClienteModel) session.load(ClienteModel.class, id);
    }
}
```

**Pessoa DAO**

```
package dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import model.PessoaModel;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import util.HibernateUtil;

public class PessoaDao implements Serializable {

    public Exception incluir(PessoaModel obj) {
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
            Serializable ser = session.save(obj);
            t.commit();
            session.close();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex;
        }
    }

    public Exception alterar(PessoaModel obj) {
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(obj);
            t.commit();
            session.close();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<PessoaModel> consultar(String filtro) {
        String sql = "from " + PessoaModel.class.getName() + filtro;

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        ArrayList lista = (ArrayList<PessoaModel>) session.createQuery(sql).list();
        t.commit();
        session.close();
        return lista;
    }

    public Exception excluir(PessoaModel pessoa) {
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(pessoa);
            t.commit();
            session.close();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex;
        }
    }

    public PessoaModel get(long id) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        return (PessoaModel) session.load(PessoaModel.class, id);
    }
}
```

**Trecho que pego os dados da Pessoa e do Cliente para persistir**

```
ClienteController clientecontroller = new ClienteController();
                    PessoaController pessoacontroller = new PessoaController();
                    PessoaModel pessoa = new PessoaModel();
                    ClienteModel cliente = new ClienteModel();
                    cliente.setCLI_LIMITECRED(Double.parseDouble(edtCLI_LIMITECRED.getText()));
                    pessoa.setPES_NOME(edtPES_NOME.getText());
                    pessoa.setPES_FANTASIA(edtPES_FANTASIA.getText());
                    pessoa.setPES_FISICA((cbPES_FISICA.isSelected() ? 'S' : 'N'));
                    pessoa.setPES_CPFCNPJ(edtPES_CPFCNPJ.getText());
                    pessoa.setPES_RGIE(edtPES_RGIE.getText());

                    pessoa.setPES_ENDERECO(edtPES_ENDERECO.getText());
                    pessoa.setPES_NUMERO(edtPES_NUMERO.getText());
                    pessoa.setPES_COMPLEMENTO(edtPES_COMPLEMENTO.getText());               
                    pessoa.setPES_BAIRRO(edtPES_BAIRRO.getText());
                    pessoa.setPES_CIDADE(edtPES_CIDADE.getText());
                    pessoa.setPES_UF(edtPES_UF.getText());
                    pessoa.setPES_CEP(edtPES_CEP.getText());
                    pessoa.setPES_FONE1(edtPES_FONE1.getText());
                    pessoa.setPES_FONE2(edtPES_FONE2.getText());
                    pessoa.setPES_CELULAR(edtPES_CELULAR.getText());
                    pessoa.setPES_SITE(edtPES_SITE.getText());
                    pessoa.setPES_EMAIL(edtPES_EMAIL.getText());
                    pessoa.setPES_ATIVO((cbPES_ATIVO.isSelected() ? 'S' : 'N'));               
                    //pessoacontroller.gravar(pessoa, "incluir");
                    cliente.setPessoamodel(pessoa);


                        clientecontroller.gravar(cliente, "incluir");
                        mensagem = "Dados Gravados com Sucesso";
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    mensagem = "Erro na Gravação do Usuário \n" + ex.getMessage();
                }
```

Comment: você precisa salvar pessoa antes de salvar cliente

Comment: Entendi, mas o hibernate não faz automático? E com as session factory não faz isso pra mim? E como você me recomenda fazer?? Meu professor disse que o hibernate faz sozinho

Comment: Justamente..  o Erro claramente diz que você está tentando salvar um valor "transient" em uma relação não nula. Você pode alterar a relação entre ClienteModel->PessoaModel para efetuar um cascade no momento de persistir o ClienteModel (persistindo a pessoa neste momento..). Ou, você precisa salvar a PessoaModel e ai então salvar o ClienteModel p/ o JPA ter uma entidade "managed" do PessoaModel para poder relacionar com o ClienteModel (o valor da FK deve existir, basicamente)

Comment: Como faço esse cascade? consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Tenta alterar o mapeamendo da relação ClienteModel->PessoaModel p/ fazer cascade.

`@OneToOne(/*... */, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`

Comment: @IsraelMerljak Fiz esta modificação, porém deu o mesmo erro que não cadastrei pessoa antes

Comment: @IsraelMerljak Eu mudei para LAZY @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) E agora ele deu outro erro

Comment: @IsraelMerljak Da uma olhada no Erro, eu modifiquei a pergunta

Comment: haha, cara.. então salva o PessoaModel primeiro, depois salva o ClienteModel. Qual erro q deu agora? (Eu n tenho mta experiencia com a API especifica do Hibernate, prefiro usar a do JPA mesmo..)

Comment: Aquele erro é pq deu conflito nas restrições da base.. durante a inserção ele tentou colocar um valor inexistente (pelo menos no momento da tentativa) p/ o campo que tem a constraint FK_CLIENTE_PESSOA..

Comment: @IsraelMerljak foda, não sei o que fazer kkkk

Comment: @IsraelMerljak tem alguma ideia?

Comment: @IsraelMerljak Olha o edit, ele esta colocando a chave certa, eu consegui puxar os dados do sql com Log4j

Comment: Precisava muito resolver isso )): @IsraelMerljak

Comment: putz.. não tive tempo de ver cara. tava no trampo D:
Me parece que pode ser um problema na base. Não faz muito sentido esse erro se as inserções estão na ordem correta. Pode ser uma constraint mal feita.

Comment: @IsraelMerljak ta certo, pes_codigo da tabela cliente esta relacionada com pes_codigo da tabela pessoa

Comment: Cara eu descobri o erro @IsraelMerljak eu tirei a chave estrangeira, e percebi que no banco de dados esta colocando o PES_CODIGO = 2 e o CLI_CODIGO = 2, parece que pra fazer o insert esta executando a sequencia duas vezes...

Comment: Porém o hibernate pega a sequencia do primeiro insert e coloca, ai da erro.. como me ajuda a prosseguir?

Comment: Cara, uma dúvida. essa base de dados foi criada com o Hibernate ou ela é feita na mão? (Vou ver se consigo reproduzir aqui teu projeto e ver o que acontece)

Comment: CONSEGUI!! A TRIGGER DA SEQUENCE NO BANCO ESTAVA GERANDO SEQUENCIA ERRADA JUNTO COM O HIBERNATE, DESATIVEI A TRIGGER DAS SEQUENCE E AGORA ESTOU USANDO APENAS O HIBERNATE PARA SEQUENCIAS!!!